Create server locally with laravel but can not accessed
i create server locally on my PC, with laravel project and running with command
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
i try to access with google chrome type http://192.168.099:8000 and it can be access. but when i try to open with my android project, the ip address can not be access. whats wrong with that ?
i can connect both, with browser and with android device

Both using the same WiFi?

this may work:
Find your PC's local IP address:
Run the following command in your command prompt or terminal:
ipconfig (Windows)
ifconfig (Mac/Linux)
Note the IPv4 Address (e.g., 192.168.1.100).
Serve your Laravel application:
Start your Laravel development server with:
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
Allow port 8000 through your firewall:
Open your firewall settings and allow incoming connections on port 8000.
Access from your Android device:
Open the browser on your Android device and type:
http://192.168.1.100:8000
Replace 192.168.1.100 with your actual PC’s IP address.
